# Set user.roles to the value selected by the user on registration

Tags: meteor

I can't figure out how to set user.roles to the value selected by the user when they complete registration. The code below works however it sets roles to both teacher and student instead of what the user has selected. I'm using:

- alanning:roles
- useraccounts:bootstrap

useraccounts:bootstrap

Path: `server.startup.js`

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

console.log('Running server startup code...');

Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {
Roles.setRolesOnUserObj(user, ['student','teacher']);

if (options.profile) {
// include the user profile
user.profile = options.profile
}

// other user object changes...
// ...

return user;
});

});
```

path: `lib/config/at_config.js`

```
AccountsTemplates.addField({
_id: "roles",
type: "radio",
displayName: "Account type",
required: true,
select: [
{
text: "Student",
value: "student",
}, {
text: "Teacher",
value: "teacher",
}
],
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to add roles to the user, based upon a value selected by the user? So it's the line Roles.setRolesOnUserObj(user, ['student','teacher']); that doesn't work? It seems that you're assigning both roles?

Comment: Yeh, I'm not sure how I get use the users selection and pass it accross so that I assign that specific selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AccountsTemplates.addField` stores fields under `profile`, so you should be able to fetch the selected role with something like this:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function (options, user) {

   if (options.profile && options.profile.roles) {
      // include the user profile
      Roles.setRolesOnUserObj(user, options.profile.roles);
   }
}
```

A similiar question found here:

https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/issues/290

Comment: Thanks @smoksnes you really helped me out there. I was stumped. That completely solved my problem.

Comment: Great. Glad to help. Have fun with Meteor!